# How to encrypt and add password to a zip file via ADF or Azure logic app?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have some csv data in blob storage. I want to email them with a password encryption as an attachment.I can zip them in ADF pipeline. Now I am using logic app to send the email. Is there any way to encrypt and add password to this zip file by using ADF or Azure logic app? If not, what is the best way to solve it? Thank you.